# android maps displayed multiple markers (LatLng from sqlite)

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps-markers, android-maps

i use google maps with get (user) device location (GPS Location) in my android app, and insert into database (SQLite) latitude and longitude and adress !

now i want displayed multiple location with LatLng read from database ... no problem in create marker, but in marker info (country, city ...) only show last inserted location for all markers !

this my code :

```
private void displayMultiplePoint() {
        if (LOCATION_TABLE.size() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; LOCATION_TABLE.size() > i; i++) {
                int id = LOCATION_TABLE.get(i).getId();
                lat = LOCATION_TABLE.get(i).getLatitude();
                lng = LOCATION_TABLE.get(i).getLongitude();
                place = LOCATION_TABLE.get(i).getPlace();
                rate = LOCATION_TABLE.get(i).getRate();
                drawMarker(new LatLng(lat, lng), "city", place, rate);
                displayToast(id + "" + place);
            }
        }
    }

    private void drawMarker(final LatLng point, final String city, final String place, final float rate) {
        mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {
                View v = null;
                try {
                    v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_contents, null);
                    ImageView map_image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.maps_image);
                    map_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.runhd);
                    TextView city_txt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.maps_city);
                    city_txt.setText(city);
                    TextView place_txt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.maps_place);
                    place_txt.setText(place);
                    RatingBar rate_bar = (RatingBar) v.findViewById(R.id.exercise_display_rate);
                    rate_bar.setRating(rate);
                } catch (Exception ev) {
                    System.out.print(ev.getMessage());
                }
                return v;
            }
        });
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(point);
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(point, 6));
    }
```

i show toast form rowId from lcation table in databse, and displaled 3 row id : 1, 2, 3 but in marker info show last id (id no : 3)

this my fragment :

[image]

thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Use Cursor through your database and get data rows (and show in Toast)
but 
my code change to this :

```
private void displayMultiplePoint() {
        Cursor cursor = DB_HELPER.LOCATION_MARKERS();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            for (int i = 0; cursor.getCount() > i; i++) {
                int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));
                double lat = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("latitude"));
                double lng = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex("longitude"));
                String place = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("place"));
                float rate = cursor.getFloat(cursor.getColumnIndex("rate"));
                displayToast(id + ", " + place + rate);
                cursor.moveToNext();
                drawMarker(new LatLng(lat, lng));
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
```

i get arg0.getId form : (m0, m1, m2 ...)

```
public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0)
```

(is unique for each marker) then select data by id where id = arg0

Answer (score 1):

I have many solution for your case But at first :

Your fall with `setInfoWindowAdapter` method it's just **invoked one time**, So after you iterated your database items and passing info through `drawMarker` it's just shown the last modified (saved) data from the variables, So i suggest to move it in your for loop (I know it's not a perfect solution) :

```
 for (int i = 0; LOCATION_TABLE.size() > i; i++) {
            int id = LOCATION_TABLE.get(i).getId();
            lat = LOCATION_TABLE.get(i).getLatitude();
            lng = LOCATION_TABLE.get(i).getLongitude();
            place = LOCATION_TABLE.get(i).getPlace();
            rate = LOCATION_TABLE.get(i).getRate();
            drawMarker(new LatLng(lat, lng), "city", place, rate);
            displayToast(id + "" + place);
            ..........
             @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {
            View v = null;
            try {
                v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_contents, null);
                ImageView map_image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.maps_image);
                map_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.runhd);
                TextView city_txt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.maps_city);
                city_txt.setText("city");
                TextView place_txt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.maps_place);
                place_txt.setText(place);
                RatingBar rate_bar = (RatingBar) v.findViewById(R.id.exercise_display_rate);
                rate_bar.setRating(rate);
            } catch (Exception ev) {
                System.out.print(ev.getMessage());
            }
            return v;
            ......
        }
```

**2nd Solution** Using [**`Cursor`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) through your database and use it anywhere (This is will be awesome).

**3rd** Using [**`Clustering`**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering) Algorithm   in [google_maps-utils-example](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils).

Comment: about this "Solution Using Cursor through your database and use it anywhere (This is will be awesome)." You have an example

Comment: @ghasemdeh super easy just implement it like docs, and invoke any data you need, with out for loop.

Comment: please go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/871/sqlite/5128/reading-data-from-a-cursor)

Answer (score 1):

The info window is being shown for only last marker because `setInfoWindowAdapter()` sets info window for the entire map. Inside `setInfoWindowAdapter()` you need to associate marker argument with corresponding data.

1. You need to maintain a marker to data map.

   ```
   Map<Marker, Place> markerToPlaceMap = new HashMap<>();
   ```

   where, `Place` is a class to hold city, place, and rating.

   ```
   class Place {
       public String city, place;
       public float rating;
   }
   ```

   Note: Please change members to private and implement getters and setters as per your suitability.
2. Next, Your `drawMarker()` will change as follows. It needs to add the `marker` and it's related `place` to `markerToPlace` map.

   ```
   private void drawMarker(final LatLng point, final String city, final String place, final float rate) {
       MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
       markerOptions.position(point);
       Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
       mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(point, 6));
       markerToPlaceMap.put(marker, new Place(city, place, rating));
   }
   ```
3. Finally, you will override `GoogleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter()` and access `Place` related to a `marker` for setting corresponding info contents.

   ```
   mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

       @Override
       public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
           return null;
       }

       @Override
       public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
           View v = null;
           try {

               v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_contents, null);

               ImageView map_image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.maps_image);
               map_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.runhd);

               TextView city_txt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.maps_city);
               city_txt.setText(markerToPlace.get(marker).city); // <- Check how corresponding place for a marker is fetched and used

               TextView place_txt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.maps_place);
               place_txt.setText(markerToPlace.get(marker).place);

               RatingBar rate_bar = (RatingBar) v.findViewById(R.id.exercise_display_rate);
               rate_bar.setRating(markerToPlace.get(marker).rate);

           } catch (Exception ev) {
               System.out.print(ev.getMessage());
           }
           return v;
       }
   });
   ```